# Merging Two Objects with arrays inside of it

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, javascript-objects

I'm trying to merge two javascript objects that has inside of it arrays and other elements. Let me give you an example.

```
{
        "addresses": [
            {
                "type": "email",
                "tags": [
                    "Responsável",
                    "Pai"
                ],
                "address": "johndoepai1@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "type": "phone",
                "tags": [
                    "Responsável",
                    "Mãe"
                ],
                "address": "551138839332"
            },
            {
                "type": "email",
                "tags": [
                    "Mãe"
                ],
                "address": "johndoemae1@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "type": "email",
                "tags": [
                    "Aluno"
                ],
                "address": "johndoealuno1@gmail.com"
            }
        ],
        "class": [
            "Sala 1",
            "Sala 2",
            "Sala 3"
        ],
        "fullname": "John Doe 1",
        "eid": "2",
        "invisible": true,
        "see_all": false
    },
    {
        "addresses": [
            {
                "type": "email",
                "tags": [
                    "Responsável",
                    "Pai"
                ],
                "address": "johndoepai2@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "type": "email",
                "tags": [
                    "Responsável",
                    "Pai"
                ],
                "address": "johndoepai3@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "type": "phone",
                "tags": [
                    "Pai"
                ],
                "address": "5519985504400"
            },
            {
                "type": "phone",
                "tags": [
                    "Responsável",
                    "Mãe"
                ],
                "address": "551138839333"
            },
            {
                "type": "email",
                "tags": [
                    "Mãe"
                ],
                "address": "11 983340440"
            },
            {
                "type": "email",
                "tags": [
                    "Aluno"
                ],
                "address": ""
            }
        ],
        "class": [
            "Sala 4",
            "Sala 5",
            "Sala 6"
        ],
        "fullname": "John Doe 1",
        "eid": "2",
        "invisible": false,
        "see_all": true
    }
```

As you can see, we can have arrays inside with some strings in those arrays.
I've tried to do it using some recursion, but had no success.

```
function mergeObjects(target, source){
    var item, tItem, o, idx;
    if (typeof source == 'undefined') {
      return source;
    } else if (typeof target == 'undefined') {
      return target;
    }

    for (var prop in source) {
        item = source[prop];
        //check if the first element is indeed an object.
        if (typeof item == 'object' && item !== null) {
            //if the first item is an array
          if (_.isArray(item) && item.length) {
              //dealing with array of primitives
              if (typeof item[0] != 'object') {
                  item.forEach(function(conteudo){
                      //push to the target all the elements;
                      target[prop].push(conteudo);
                  });
              }else{
                //dealing with array of objects;
                for(var attr in item){
                    idx = {};
                    tItem = target[attr]
                    mergeObjects(tItem,item);
                }
              }
          }//if its a normal object
          else {
           // deal with object
           mergeObjects(target[prop],item);
         }

        } else {
             // item is a primitive, just copy it over
             target[prop] = item;
           }
    }
    return target;
}
```

I Expected this:

```
  {
        "addresses": [
            {
                "type": "email",
                "tags": [
                    "Responsável",
                    "Pai"
                ],
                "address": "johndoepai2@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "type": "email",
                "tags": [
                    "Responsável",
                    "Pai"
                ],
                "address": "johndoepai3@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "type": "phone",
                "tags": [
                    "Pai"
                ],
                "address": "5519985504400"
            },
            {
                "type": "phone",
                "tags": [
                    "Responsável",
                    "Mãe"
                ],
                "address": "551138839333"
            },
            {
                "type": "email",
                "tags": [
                    "Mãe"
                ],
                "address": "11 983340440"
            },
            {
                "type": "email",
                "tags": [
                    "Aluno"
                ],
                "address": ""
            }
        ],
        "class": [
            "Sala 4",
            "Sala 5",
            "Sala 6",
            "Sala 1",
            "Sala 2",
            "Sala 3"
        ],
        "fullname": "John Doe 1",
        "eid": "2",
        "invisible": true,
        "see_all": false
    }

"fullname": "John Doe 1",
  "eid": "1234",
  "classes": [
    "Sala 1",
    "Sala 2",
    "Sala 3",
    "Sala 4",
    "Sala 5",
    "Sala 6"
  ],
  "addresses": [{
    "type": "phone",
    "tags": [
      "Responsável",
      "Mãe"
    ],
    "address": "551138839332"
  }, {
    "type": "email",
    "tags": [
      "Mãe"
    ],
    "address": "johndoemae1@gmail.com"
  }, {
    "type": "email",
    "tags": [
      "Aluno"
    ],
    "address": "johndoealuno1@gmail.com"
  }, {
    "type": "email",
    "tags": [
      "Responsável",
      "Pai"
    ],
    "address": "johndoepai2@gmail.com"
  }, {
    "type": "email",
    "tags": [
      "Responsável",
      "Pai"
    ],
    "address": "johndoepai3@gmail.com"
  }, {
    "type": "phone",
    "tags": [
      "Pai"
    ],
    "address": "5519985504400"
  }, {
    "type": "phone",
    "tags": [
      "Responsável",
      "Mãe"
    ],
    "address": "551138839333"
  }],
  "invisible": true,
  "see_all": true
}
```

But what i got was this, as you can see, some email elements are missing.

```
{
    "addresses": [
        {
            "type": "email",
            "tags": [
                "Responsável",
                "Pai"
            ],
            "address": "johndoepai2@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "type": "email",
            "tags": [
                "Responsável",
                "Pai"
            ],
            "address": "johndoepai3@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "type": "phone",
            "tags": [
                "Pai"
            ],
            "address": "5519985504400"
        },
        {
            "type": "phone",
            "tags": [
                "Responsável",
                "Mãe"
            ],
            "address": "551138839333"
        },
        {
            "type": "email",
            "tags": [
                "Mãe"
            ],
            "address": "11 983340440"
        },
        {
            "type": "email",
            "tags": [
                "Aluno"
            ],
            "address": ""
        }
    ],
    "class": [
        "Sala 4",
        "Sala 5",
        "Sala 6",
        "Sala 1",
        "Sala 2",
        "Sala 3"
    ],
    "fullname": "John Doe 1",
    "eid": "2",
    "invisible": true,
    "see_all": false
}
```

Order of elements is not a problem.
Which point of the recursion tree did i miss?

Comment: you can try taking a look into the underscore library: http://underscorejs.org/ to see if the same functionality can be achieved.

Comment: @JamesonYu from underscone, none can help for what ive searched. I've tried the _.merge from lodash, and it didnt behave how i expected.

Comment: Is your second code block what you expect the result to be?  If not, then please show us what you expect the result to be.

Comment: @jfriend00 fixed. I forgot to put what i got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you have to merge the arrays yourself first.  Or you can use something nice like [Lodash's mergeWidth](https://lodash.com/docs#mergeWith) [Ramda's R.mergeWith](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#mergeWith) (see below for sample code for Ramda).

You want something like the native Object.assign (limited browser support, so it will have to be polyfilled) or whatever merge your JS library has.

The problem you're running into is how all of these merge implementations handle duplicate keys.  Usually the key will be set to the last value passed in:

```js
var thing1 = {
  someProperty: 'foo'
};

var thing2 = {
  someProperty: 'bar'
};

var result1 = Object.assign({}, thing1, thing2);
// -> {someProperty: 'bar'} (set to the last value passed in, in thing2)

var result2 = Object.assign({}, thing2, thing1);
// -> {someProperty: 'foo'} (again set to the last value passed in, in thing1)

// Make the Stackoverflow snippet display the output.
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(result1, null, 2);
document.body.innerHTML += '<br>' + JSON.stringify(result2, null, 2);
```

Works the same way with your example, except the property is a more complicated array.  It's just being set to the last array passed in:

```js
var thing1 = {
  someList: [1, 2, 3]
};

var thing2 = {
  someList: [4, 5, 6]
};

var result = Object.assign({}, thing1, thing2);
// -> {someList: [4, 5, 6]}

// Make the Stackoverflow snippet display the output.
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
```

If you use something nice like Ramda, you can merge and specify a function to control the behavior when keys are equal, like in your case.  Here we can check if the value is an array, then concatenate if so.  Otherwise, return the latest value (as described above):

```js
var thing1 = {someList: [1, 2, 3]};
var thing2 = {someList: [4, 5, 6]};

var dupeMergeFn = function(a, b) {
  return (Array.isArray(a)) ? a.concat(b) : b;
};

var result = R.mergeWith(dupeMergeFn, thing1, thing2);

// Make the Stackoverflow snippet display the output.
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.19.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the problem is, i should keep both of the contents, i cant lost one of them like in those examples.

Comment: I updated the post to show how you can use Ramda's mergeWith to achieve what you want.  Should work a similar way with Lodash's mergeWith